# Is it possible to use `ref` for a TextNode?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, dom, jsx

This:

```
import React from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";

let $container;

render(
  <b ref={e => ($container = e)}>
    {"one"}two{"six"}
  </b>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);

console.log($container);
```

will get me the `<b>` element:

```
<b>
  <!-- react-text: 2 -->
  "one"
  <!-- /react-text -->
  <!-- react-text: 3 -->
  "two"
  <!-- /react-text -->
  <!-- react-text: 4 -->
  "six"
  <!-- /react-text -->
</b>
```

But, what if I want a reference to one of the TextNodes?
Is there a public api for this? Maybe a special `type` for TextNodes so I can pass props to `createElement`?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Hard to explain because I'm not even using react. I'm trying to do something similar with a library called nativejsx and wanted to know if this is possible with react.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't have a ref to those string literals with JSX. What this code is transformed to is:

```
render(React.createElement(
  "b",
  { ref: function ref(e) {
      return $container = e;
    } },
  "one",
  "two",
  "six"
), document.getElementById("root"));
```

They are not React elements but strings, you can check it with the [Babel Repl](https://babeljs.io/repl). One way to solve this problem is to wrap those elements in `<span>` tags, so then you can have a ref attached.

```
$refs = {};

render(
  <b>
    <span ref={e => $refs.one = e}>one</span>
    <span ref={e => $refs.two = e}>{'two'}</span>
    <span ref={e => $refs.three = e}>three</span>
  </b>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

Comment: alas, spans won't flow the same as text nodes in all layouts

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I did: I created a component that solely consists of a text and referenced its `TextNode` in the DOM with `ReactDOM.findDOMNode` like so:

```
class TextNode extends React.Component {

  componentDidMount() {
      this.textNode = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this); // Will be the DOM text node
  }

  render() {
    return this.props.text;
  }

}
```

In your example I could do something like this:

```
render(
  <b>
    <TextNode text={"one"} />
    <TextNode text="two" />
    <TextNode text={"six"} />
  </b>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

The resulting HTML would not have any `span`s:

```
<b>onetwosix</b>
```

while the DOM would have a `<b>` element with 3 text nodes inside.